# I need help creating this Java Map?

Tags: java

I have a text file with this data:

```
a, 0, 10, 7, 
b, 22, 0, 13, 
c, 4, 12, 0
```

I want to create a Map with the key being the letter and the value being an `ArrayList<Integer>` of the `int` values associated with that letter.

This is what I have tried:

```
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
        list.add(scanner.nextLine());
       
    }
     
    Map <String, ArrayList <Integer>> map = new HashMap();
    //map.put(list.get(0).charAt(0), value);
    
}
```

The key part of the map works by getting the letter but I am unsure how to correctly implement the value to be the `ArrayList <Integer>` values.

Comment: I was wondering if you would every have another line which could also start with a letter that was previously used?  In such cases it is typical to merge those numbers in the same list as the previously used key (since maps cannot have duplicate keys).

Answer (score 3):

You only need one loop to iterate over the lines and grab the first + remaining columns

For example,

```
Map <String, ArrayList <Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*");
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, 1, parts.length))
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(toList());
    map.put(parts[0], numbers);
}
```

Note: You may want to remove the commas from the end of each line

Comment: I love both of you. Commenting on an arraylist issue at 3:30 GMT+1 makes us special. Human beings identified as females and heterosexuals love it.

Comment: I don't like editing answers of others but I believe you meant `map.put(parts[0], numbers)`  And you may want to use one of the `compute` methods to allow for duplicate keys.

Comment: @WJS Good catch. Regarding duplicates, maps cannot allow them anyway, so not sure I understand. Unless you mean merging the values of duplicate keys, but that seemed outside scope of the question

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes. Maps can't allow duplicates.  It has been my experience on this site that quite often the OP's don't provide the full story (usually its just an accident of omission). So if another line starting with the same letter were to appear I would think it would need to be added the to existing list for that key. For example, this seems like a lot of work to process three lines of four tokens. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is a somewhat different approach.

- allow for less specific formatting and trailing white space.
- Uses the `Files.lines` method to stream the lines.
- Presumes there are more than three lines in the file so add a merge function to take care of duplicate keys, if they should arise.

```
String sourceFile = "<Your file here>";
Map<String, List<Integer>> map;
try {
    map = Files.lines(Path.of(sourceFile))
            .map(String::trim)
            .map(str -> str.split("\\s*,\\s*"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> Arrays
                    .stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length))
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                    (list1,list2)-> {list1.addAll(list2); return list1;}));
} catch (IOException fne) {
    fne.printStackTrace();
}
map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

So given a file like the following:

```
a, 0, 10, 7, 
b, 22, 0, 13, 
c, 4,12,0 
c,4,12,12
a,9,2,3
```

Prints

```
a=[0, 10, 7, 9, 2, 3]
b=[22, 0, 13]
c=[4, 12, 0, 4, 12, 12]
```